# How to get values from any running process?

Tags: process

Is there a way to get values and their changes from a running application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch variables and memory change as the application executes using a [debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger), such as [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) or the [Visual Studio debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx). Most decent debuggers allow you to set watchpoints so that the execution stops once a variable is modified and all of them allow you to set [breakpoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint) at specific code locations.

Keep in mind that usually you will have to compile your application with specific flags for debugging to be practical. You will need at least debugging symbols for your debugger to be able to associate memory addresses with variable names, and you will also need to keep compiler optimisations to a minimum, since they can mangle the executable code enough to make it unrecognisable with regards to the original source code.